# Jenkins will not copy a file. Why not?

Tags: jenkins

I have a Jenkins job that does a `Delphi build` and creates an `EXE`.

I want to copy that `EXE to a network location`.  I have tried a couple of ways including

- a straight batch command with `copy`
- ArtifactDeployer
- CopyDeployer

and everything I try results in an `Access is Denied error`.

I am using the `Jenkins user` both for Windows, the `Apache service`, and for Jenkins itself.

The file itself is not locked as I can manually do the move that I am trying to automate with Jenkins.

Anyone have any ideas how to move a file from the `Jenkins workspace` to a `network share`?

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing the user that Jenkins runs under is not the same as the one you tested with manually.  If you fix up the permissions on the destination directory, any of the above methods should work.

Answer (score 0):

your issue seems to linked to the jenkins user

I assume that if within a script you launch a command like : **whoiam** you will see that the user used by jenkins may be tomcat7 if you have jenkins as a webapp.